# prevent saving data to localStorage until all inputs filled

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have two inputs. one for login and another one for password. But before to storing in the LocalStorage I need to validate inputs. the point is that data save to LS despite empty password field. try to use Break but seems not successfully.
 the issue how to prevent saving data to Local Storage until user fills all inputs.

```
  function validate() {
  var userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".form__input");
  var regex = /[^a-z|^A-Z|^0-9|^\s^\w+^\"']/;

  for(var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    if(userInput[i].value === "") {
      alert("Please fill all required fields!");
      break;
    }
    else if(userInput[i].value.match(regex)) {
      alert("Please use an appropriate symbols!");
      break;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('Login', userInput[0].value);
  }
}
```

Comment: try taking out the localStorage statement outside the for loop. In for loop return userInput[0].value and assign it to localStorage out side. And also console log userInput to make sure you are the getting the right values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an else statement in the end.

```js
function validate() {
  if(validateFields){
      localStorage.setItem('Login', userInput[0].value);
    }
 }

function validateFields(){
 var retVal = false;
 var userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".form__input");
  var regex = /[^a-z|^A-Z|^0-9|^\s^\w+^\"']/;
 for(var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    if(userInput[i].value === "") {
      alert("Please fill all required fields!");
      break;
    }
    else if(userInput[i].value.match(regex)) {
      alert("Please use an appropriate symbols!");
      break;
    }else{
      retval = true;
    }
  }
 return retval;
}
```

Note: I just refactored the code to make it work. Its a bad idea to store the user inputs such as passwords in local storage as it opens a vulnerability.